# postgres, bulk update using data from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have one target table (already populated with data) and another one (source table) from wich I need to retrieve data into first one.

target_table

```
postgres=# select id,id_user from ttasks;
 id | id_user
----+---------
  1 |
  2 |
  3 |
  4 |
  5 |
(5 rows)
```

source_table

```
postgres=# select id from tusers where active;
  id
------
 1011
 1012
 1013
 1014
(4 rows)
```

I need to update id_user column of ttasks table using id's from tusers table, so final result on ttasks should be:

```
# expected result after update [select id, id_user from ttasks;]
 id | id_user
----+---------
  1 |    1011
  2 |    1012
  3 |    1013
  4 |    1014
  5 |    1011
(5 rows)
```

What I have tried (similar to INSERT ... FROM ... statement):

```
postgres=# update ttasks t1 set id_user = q1.id from (select id from tusers where active) q1 returning t1.id,t1.id_user;
 id | id_user
----+---------
  1 |    1011  
  2 |    1011
  3 |    1011
  4 |    1011  
  5 |    1011  
(5 rows)
```

but this query allways use first id from my q1 subquery.

Any idea, help or even solution on how can I accomplish this task ?
Thank You very much!

p.s. This is my first post on this community so please be gentle with me if  something in my question is not conforming with your rules.

Comment: There is the `update t1 set c1 = t2.c2 from t2 where t2.k1 = t1.k1;` syntax; you don't need (non)scalar subqueries.

Comment: BTW: your subquery is uncorrelated. (had not seen this because I hate horizontal scrolling)

Comment: Hi, maybe I'm so blind or so stupid but, using my case study from the question, could you create a functional query using exactly my tables (ttasks t1 as target and tusers t2 as source) ? I don't see or know what pk (used in your syntax description) should I use. 
using `update ttasks t1 set id_user = t2.id from tusers t2 ` gave me the same result (same id_user all over ttasks t1 target table) and my needs are that id_user from ttasks should be populated in a recursive manner, please check `# expected result` from my question

Comment: Maybe you omitted the `where t1.k1 = t2.k2` clause? (from the question it is not clear what the keyfield for the source_table is)

Comment: tusers table (as source_table) has one column: id (also as pk) and three rows with the following values for id column: 1,2,3

Comment: ttasks table (as target_table, as table that needs to be populated) has three columns: id (also as pk), id_user (column that needs to be populated from tusers table) and task. And it has five rows with id and task columns already populated. So I need (for target_table): first row, id_user column to have value 1 (first id from tusers), second row, id_user column to have value 2, third row, id_user column to have value 3, fourth row id_user column to have value 1, fifth row id_user column to have value 2. I think things are clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after one of my friends told me that not everything could be coded in a "keep it stupid simple" manner, I wrote a plpqsql (PL/PGSQL) function that does the job for me and more than, allow to use some advanced filters inside.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION assign_workers_to_tasks(i_workers_table regclass, i_workers_table_tc text, i_tasks_table regclass, i_tasks_table_tc text, i_workers_filter text DEFAULT ''::text, i_tasks_filter text DEFAULT ''::text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE workers int[]; i integer; total_workers integer; r record; get_tasks text;
begin
    i_workers_filter := 'where '||nullif(i_workers_filter,'');
    i_tasks_filter := 'where '||nullif(i_tasks_filter,'');
    EXECUTE format('select array_agg(%s) from (select %s from %s %s order by %s) q', i_workers_table_tc, i_workers_table_tc,i_workers_table, i_workers_filter,i_workers_table_tc)
    INTO workers; --available [filtered] workers
    total_workers := coalesce(array_length(workers,1),0); --total of available [filtered] workers
    IF total_workers = 0 THEN
      EXECUTE format('update %s set %s=null %s', i_tasks_table, i_tasks_table_tc, i_tasks_filter);
      RETURN;
    END IF;
    i :=1;
    get_tasks := format('select * from %s %s',i_tasks_table,i_tasks_filter); --[filtered] tasks
    FOR r IN EXECUTE (get_tasks) LOOP
      EXECUTE format('update %s set %s=%s where id = %s', i_tasks_table, i_tasks_table_tc, workers[i],r.id);
      i := i+1;
      IF i>total_workers THEN i := 1; END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
end;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION assign_workers_to_tasks(regclass, text, regclass, text, text, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

and to fulfil my own question:

```
select assign_workers_to_tasks('tusers','id','ttasks','id_user','active');
```